# How can I superclass a builtin class?

Tags: java, inheritance, code-generation

Is it possible to create a class that builtin classes extend? I found plenty of questions about subclassing builtins, but none about superclassing them. I know I could just use Object, but I hope there's a cleaner solution.

To make the question clearer, here's why I ask. I'm working on a code generation system that has its own implementations of many builtin classes, including (but not limited to) `com.thiscompany.IntegerDatum` and `com.thiscompany.StringDatum`. This was originally done so that all of these pieces of data could extend a single abstract class called `Datum`. However, it's not always necessary to extend `Datum`. In those cases,  using `java.lang.Integer` and `java.lang.String` would be far faster. I'd like to make a class that superclasses `Datum`, `java.lang.Number`, and `java.lang.String` so that methods that operate on data can also operate on those other types. Is this possible without using Object?

Comment: `Java.lang.String` is `final` you can not extends from it

Comment: I'm not trying to extend ``Java.lang.String`` - I'm trying to make it extend something else.

Comment: you can't do that without creating your own jvm :)

Comment: Certain things are not only "written down in class file bytecode". They are implemented in the JVM itself. Even if you find a way to manipulate on that level; I don't think that the result of that will be a reliable, robust, trustworthy component. More to the exact opposite of that.

Comment: @Jägermeister, that was a very helpful explanation. If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Sure thing. I was actually about to do that ... so, you are very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain things are not only "written down in class file bytecode". They are implemented in the JVM itself. Even if you find a way to manipulate on that level; I don't think that the result of that will be a reliable, robust, trustworthy component. More to the exact opposite of that.